# Is there a difference other than emphasis between "has been utterly" and "has utterly been"?

Tags: difference, word-order, emphasis

Is there any difference between:

> 1a. Ben has been **utterly** concentrated only on his work for several months.

and

> 1b. Ben has **utterly** been concentrated only on his work for several months.

or between:

> 2a. Tom has answered **literally** all the questions correctly.

and

> 2b. Tom has **literally** answered all the questions correctly.

The first sentence of each pair has been marked as incorrect on my English test. As far as I am concerned, the only difference is where you put the emphasis, or is there any kind of grammatical rule that I am not aware of?

Comment: Did your teacher explain why? As far as I can see neither of the first pair is very idiomatic and in the second pair the first is better than the second.

Comment: They didn't, but I'm gonna ask! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In 1. your second example is wrong.
**Utterly** is in an unnatural position. Also, we would not say that someone **has been concentrated**. It's not idiomatic. Someone **has concentrated** on his work.
Apart from this, while **utterly** is possible, it doesn't fit naturally in front of concentrated. If you had to use a modifier here, **totally** is more natural and you would need to omit **only**.

So, your first sentence should read either:

> Ben has concentrated only on his work for several months.
> or
> Ben has concentrated totally on his work for several months.

Your second examples are also problematic.

To begin with, **literally** doesn't fit in this context. **Literally** is used when someone means that his/her words are exactly true rather than being metaphorical, as in: **They were frozen stiff when they were found**. Literally, this would apply to bodies and not just to people who were cold.

Moreover, **to answer literally** means to answer in a literal manner, which is not what you intend.

To **literally answer all the questions** is trying to emphasise Tom's accomplishments.

So: >**Tom has literally answered all the questions correctly** is possible although **literally** serves little purpose here unless you are implying that it was a great accomplishment.